# Why do I keep getting the same value of a variable for each iteration? c++

Tags: c++, variables

i am new to c++ and I keep getting the same value for variable 'w'..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define NOEXE 10
#define winit 0.9
#define wfinal 0.2

int main()
{
    for (int nExeNo = 0; nExeNo<NOEXE; nExeNo++)
    {
        double w;

        w = (((NOEXE - nExeNo)/NOEXE)*((NOEXE - nExeNo)/NOEXE))*(winit - wfinal) + wfinal;
        std::cout << w << "\n";
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
0.9
0.2
0.2
0.2 .......
```

Comment: As a side-note you should use const variables instead of those `#define` directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(NOEXE - nExeNo)/NOEXE` is done entirely in integer arithmetic. Since `nExeNo < NOEXE` the entire previous expression is always zero.

Thus you are left only with the final term `wfinal`.

To force floating point arithmetic, at least one operand must be of a floating point type (in your case a double). So to clean up, and get rid of the nasty macros, define your constants as follows:

```
constexpr int    NOEXE   = 10; // use const instead of constexpr for C++03
constexpr double NOEXE_D = NOEXE;
constexpr double winit   = 0.9;
constexpr double wfinal  = 0.2;
```

And use `NOEXE_D` in the calculation instead. I.e. `(NOEXE_D - nExeNo)/NOEXE_D)`.

Comment: adding
        double noexe = NOEXE;
        double nexeno = nExeNo;
before w solves the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @YasirDharala - Looping with a double "index" is ill-advised. You'll get erratic behavior if `NOEXE` grows too large.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `NOEXE` and `nExeNo` are integers and so the individual calculations with them are rounded to the nearest integer: `NOEXE - nExeNo)/NOEXE` will always be rounded to either 1 or 0. It will be rounded to 1 for the first iteration and then 0 for all the proceeding.

If you change `NOEXE` to a float it should work

```
#define NOEXE 10.0
```

And the results will be as follows

```
0.9
0.767
0.648
0.543
0.452
0.375
0.312
0.263
0.228
0.207
```

Generally, it is good practice to define the type and use a `const` rather than `#define`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are doing integer division, not floating one as you intended

Let's focus on the `(NOEXE - nExeNo)/NOEXE)` part in the loop

```
for (int nExeNo = 0; nExeNo<NOEXE; nExeNo++)
{
    double w;

    w = (((NOEXE - nExeNo)/NOEXE)
    std::cout << w << "\n";
}
```

You can see the print out as

```
1
0
0
...
```

The quickest way to fix this is to define NOEXE as floating point

```
#define NOEXE 10.0
```

or cast one of the operators to double

```
w = (((NOEXE - nExeNo)/(double)NOEXE)*((NOEXE - nExeNo)/(double)NOEXE))*(winit - wfinal) + wfinal;
```